# Grpc c++ client to connect in secure mode using server side tls

Tags: c++, grpc

I have grpc server in Java and client in C++, I want to connect grpc client to server in tls mode without using certificates on client side. I am using the default methods and trying to connect but getting grpc code as 12.

```
creds = grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions());
```

Note:- No issue with proto files as it works fine in insecure mode

Answer (score 0):

Which cert is your server using? If it's self-signed or not signed by a standard CA (whose root cert should be present in the standard trust store) then you need to make sure you are using a custom root cert on the client

Comment: It is signed by standard CA. Do we need to using a cert on the client?

Comment: No, using a cert on the client is for mTLS (which I assume is not what you want). Do you see any additional info in the logs other than grpc code 12 (or you can look up what that code means)